# SSRS Reports - Borders not rendering properly in reporting server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS reports which contains two tablix. Both has same number of columns, size and everything. Headers in Tablix 2 is removed and it is kept below Tablix 1. I ensured there is no gap between tablix. Basically want to view them as one table.

[image: border issue]

It is rendering properly in local and when exported to any format. When it is deployed in reporting server, there is rendering issue and borders are mis-aligned, but export from server is absolutely fine.

Thanks in Advance,
Karthick

Comment: Can you show us an example of mis-aligned borders, please.

Comment: Hi , added image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfIRT.png

Comment: How did you align the columns?

Comment: This happened to me once. I can't remember the exact property that fixed it, but it was either `CanGrow` or `CanShrink` of the textbox in the tablix.

Comment: @WolfgangKais - I align the second tablix below the first one with no space (0pt) between them. All the columns are of equal width.

Comment: @aduguid : Already Kept CanGrow and CanShrink property to 'False' in both the tablix for all columns.

Comment: Please do not align the columns by entering the same width, try to drag the width with the mouse, the designer will help you to find the correct width. To dig deeper, it yould be useful to have a look at the source code of the page displayed in the browser (F12).